# Sphinx Update xmlpipe2 data

Tags: php, sphinx

I'm running sphinx on an Ubuntu server. There is this script that generates the xml(xmlpipe2) for our PHP SphinxClient to use and do a search.

I made a few changes, added a couple attributes so I can make a couple filters for the search. But PHP SphinxClient doesn't seem to notice the new attributes I added. I think I need to update the xml data using the indexer but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to call `indexer` just like you did the first time to create the index.

each time you call indexer it runs the xmlpipe and creates a new index.

use the `--rotate` option to seamlessly recreate the index.